# My simple PHP upload script(11 lines) hangs forever on windows but not on linux

Tags: php, windows, file-upload

My very basic PHP script that uploads a file is hanging forever and never displaying any values for $_FILES variable when I click submit. This happens on Windows only. It works perfectly on Linux. I have checked the permissions on the tmp folder and checked max_upload time/speed, made sure file upload was turned on etc... No matter what I do $_FILES is still blank and the page just hangs when I click upload. Any help on this would be great. My code is below:

HTML Form:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/js/sanction/file_upload2.php?fid=entry_entry_form&amp;update=no&amp;uid=none&amp;mktingmaterials=No&amp;advance_to_next_page=No" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="entry_form_upload_target" id="entry_entry_form_upload_form" name="entry_entry_form_upload_form">
    <input type="file" name="entry_entry_form" id="entry_entry_form"  size="40" tabindex="4"/>
    <iframe id="entry_form_upload_target" name="entry_form_upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
    <input type="submit" name="Send File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP to display PHP's $_FILES variable:

```
<?php
echo "<script>console.log('Files" . json_encode($_FILES) . "');</script>";
?>
```

Has nothing to do with the difference between client side and server side programming

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: What??? Are you serious? Has nothing to do with that article

Comment: What server are you running in Windows vs in Linux?

Comment: In Linux(working): Scientific Linux release 6.9(Carbon)
In Windows(not working): Windows Server 2016